# Add shortcut on Android Lolilpop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I try to add shortcut to homescreen using code below :
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(CameraSettings.this.getActivity(),
                BackFaceStartServiceActivity.class);

```
    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME,  name);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
             Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(CameraSettings.this.getActivity(),
                    iconid));
     addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    shortcutUri = addIntent.toUri(Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    CameraSettings.this.getActivity().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

It work fine with android version under lollipop, with the lollipop it got this crash :

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Intent must include an explicit package
  name to build an android-app: Intent {  
  act=com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT (has extras) }
  at android.content.Intent.toUri(Intent.java:7292) ......
```

How could i solve it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This code works on lollipop to create a shortcut, change the variables and you're good to go.

```
  shortcut = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, cnt.getString(R.string.she));
        shortcut.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(cnt.getApplicationContext(), AopebActivity.class));

        ShortcutIconResource iconRes = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(cnt, R.drawable.share);
        shortcut.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconRes);

        cnt.sendBroadcast(shortcut);
```

Comment: what is : ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(cnt.getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), ".AopebActivity") used for in your code?